# Performing grid search on sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB on multi-core machine doesn’t use all the available CPU resources

Tags: python, linux, scikit-learn

I’m currently trying to build some text classification tools using Python and Scikit-learn.

My text is not in English and so, isn’t subject to the usual treatment of stems decomposing or other English-based Dimensionality reduction.

As a result, the TfIdf matrix gets pretty big (150,000x150,000) It can be processed using regular PC, but running a grid search on them would be too much, so I enlisted the help of Amazon Web Service to run the grid search. (My parameter set is pretty big, too)

Here is my code:

```
 # coding: utf-8  
    import os, json, codecs, nltk  
    import numpy as np  
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer,  CountVectorizer,TfidfTransformer  
    from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV  
    from time import time  
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline  
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB  
    print("Importing dataset...")  
    with open('y_data.json','r') as fp:  
        y = json.load(fp)  
    with open('dataset.json','r') as fp:  
        dataset = json.load(fp)  
    print("Importing stop words...")  
    with codecs.open('stopword.txt','r','utf-8') as fp:  
    stopword = []  
    for w in fp:  
        stopword.append(w.strip())  
    light_st = set(stopword)  
    with codecs.open('st_data.txt','r','cp874') as fp:  
    for w in fp:  
        stopword.append(w.strip())  
    heavy_st = set(stopword)  
    def pre_process_1(text):  
        return text.replace("|"," ")  
    def tokenize_1(text):  
        return text.split()  
    pipeline = Pipeline([('vec', CountVectorizer(encoding='cp874', preprocessor=pre_process_1, tokenizer=tokenize_1, stop_words=heavy_st, token_pattern=None)),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), ('clf',       MultinomialNB())])
    parameters = {  
    'vec__max_df': (0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1.0),  
    'vec__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 20000),  
    'vec__min_df': (1, 5, 10, 20, 50),  
    'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),  
    'tfidf__sublinear_tf': (True, False),  
    'vec__binary': (True, False),  
    'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),  
    'clf__alpha': (1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001)  
    }  
    if __name__ == "__main__":  
        grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)  
        t0 = time()  
        grid_search.fit(dataset, y)  
        print("done in {0}s".format(time() - t0))  
        print("Best score: {0}".format(grid_search.best_score_))  
        print("Best parameters set:")  
        best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()  
        for param_name in sorted(list(parameters.keys())):  
            print("\t{0}: {1}".format(param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

And here is the details of my software environment:

- Python3.4.2
- scikit-learn 0.15.2 (installed with Pip)
- Ubuntu Server14.04 LTS, 64 bit (using HVM)
- Tried on ec2 r3.8xlarge instance

At first, I run my model using a much smaller instance (r3.2xlarge; 8 cores) but found out from calculation that it would take quite a long time (2 days). So, I decided to scale up my machine and use the largest instance (I use r3 because my script was quite memory intensive); however, it didn't process as fast as I assumed.

When I tried to monitor the CPU load (watch -n 5 uptime)... I found out that the average CPU load never exceeds 9 even when I leave it running for some time. (From what I understand, a thirty-two core machine, when fully utilizes all of its cores, should be around 32).

I tried changing

> n_job

parameter to various numbers (8, 32, 128) with the same result. (However I think that the script tries to run as many jobs as it was instructed because when I terminate the process I would see something like... "Process ForkPoolWorker-30:" and their tracebacks whips past the screen)

Further inspection with the ps x -C python3.4 command yields that only 8 python processes are running. I deduced that this might be some kind of limitation from python or the OS (I build my AMI using t2.micro instance which doesn't have many cores) So, I decided to redo my work of rebuilt my environment from scratch including compiling Python using c3.4xlarge, and change the OS to Amazon Linux (a branch of Fedora I think) for the better compatibility with the hardware.

However, my script still never exceeded 8 cores.
Finally, using demo text classification code from the Scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html
(which use SGDClassifier instead of MultinomialNB) It can run perfectly with all thirty-two cores!

So... maybe, something to do with the grid search algorithm and Naive Bayes classifier?

I’m considering filing a bug, but would like to know first if this is an expected behavior of Naive Bayes or if I’m doing something wrong with my code?

### Updates

I can't find a way to test if the memory bandwidth has been the culprit directly. But I try to time my parallel code and CPU usage in various ways to find where, indeed, the bottleneck occurs.

### Experiment 1: perform only the vectorization and transformation.

Using my real data as input (150,000 text documents; each contains roughly 130 words)
The parameters space is about 400.
Multi-threading is done by Joblib (the same module used by Scikit-learn). I got:
Using 8 threads: done in 841.017783164978 s and use 24.636999999999993 % of CPU.
Using 16 threads: done in 842.9525656700134 s and use 24.700749999999985 % of CPU.
Using all 32 threads: done in 857.024197101593 s and use 24.242250000000013 % of CPU.

The result clearly indicates that the vectorization process is unable to scale as the processing power increases.

### Experiment 2: This time I perform only the MultinomialNB on the pre-vectorized data.

Using the parameters space of about 400 as before, I got:
Using 8 threads: done in 2102.0565922260284 s and use 25.486000000000054 % of CPU.
Using 16 threads: done in 1385.6887295246124 s and use 49.83674999999993 % of CPU.
Using all 32 threads: done in 1319.416403055191 s and use 89.90074999999997 % of CPU.

The transition from 8 threads to 16 threads shows a huge improvement. However, as the number of threads increases to 32, the total time of completion gets only slightly shorter while the CPU usage increases substantially. This point I don't quite understand.

### Experiment 3: I combine the two processes together.

Using 8 threads: done in 3385.3253166675568 s and use 25.68999999999995 % of CPU.
Using 16 threads: done in 2066.499200105667 s and use 49.359249999999996 % of CPU.
Using all 32 threads: done in 2018.8800330162048 s and use 54.55375000000004 % of CPU.

There are some discrepancy between the time I've got from my own parallel code and that of the GridsearchCV, but this could be because the simplification I've done in my code (I'm not doing cross validation or full parameters iteration like in Gridsearch)

### conclusions

From my test, I conclude that. (And please correct me if I’m wrong)

1. The vectorization phase use memory much more intensive; thus, most likely to saturate the bandwidth. This can be observe from the time of completion and CPU utilization that it hits some kind of bottleneck and didn't scale. However, it was a relatively quick process. (I eliminate IO-bound as all data is stored on RAM, and the memory usage during that time is about 30%)
2. MultinomialNB uses memory less intensive than the vectorizer; most of the computation seems to be processed in-core. So, it can scale better than the vectorizer (8 > 16) but after that, it also hit some kind of bottle neck, and the MultinomialNB takes more time than the vectorizer.
3. When combine two processes together, the completion time shows the same trend as MultinomialNB because, in my opinion, the memory bandwidth might be the bottleneck during the vectorization phase but that phase is relatively short compare to the MultinomialNB. So, if the number of concurrent tasks is low, it is possible to do those two phases together simultaneously and not saturate the bandwidth, but when the number of processes is high enough, there will be sufficient number of concurrent processes performing the vectorization to saturate the bandwidth; thereby, forcing the operating system to reduce the running process. (Explain only 8-9 running python process I found earlier)
4. I'm not very sure but I think that the reason why SGDClassifier can use 100% CPU is because SGDClassifier has much longer in-core processing time than the MultinomialNB. So, in each iteration, much of the time is devoted to compute SGDClassifier in-core rather than doing vectorization, and the fact that SGDClassifier takes a long time to compute reduce the chance of many workers getting to the vectorization phase simultaneously (as each vectorization task is relatively short but memory intensive)

I think my best bet now is to go for the cluster computing. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your jobs are all memory-bound.

Naive Bayes is an extremely simple model, and its training algorithms consists of a single (sparse) matrix multiplication and a few sums. Similarly, tf-idf is very simple to compute: it sums over its inputs, computes a few logs, and stores the result.

In fact, NB is *so* simple that the bottleneck of this program is almost certainly in `CountVectorizer`, which transforms in-memory data structures several times until it gets all its term counts crammed into the right matrix format. You're likely to hit a memory bandwidth bottleneck if you do a lot of that in parallel.

(This is all educated guesswork, but it's based on my involvement with in scikit-learn development. I'm one of the authors of `MultinomialNB` and one of many people who have hacked on `CountVectorizer` to speed it up.)

Comment: Thank you, I never take a look at that angle before. If that is the case, I think I might have to go for the clustering.
Are there any ways to confirm it for sure?
As of now, I found stream benchmark that seems to be able to give a reliable benchmark of the memory bandwidth, and Intel® Performance Counter Monitor, which, from the description I read, should be able to tell the byte read / write from and to the controller. However, I’m not sure if it could be used reliably inside the amazon virtualization as a lot of the number seems to be zero and unusable.

Comment: @PawinP One thing you can do to check (see also updated answer) is to not fit the Naive Bayes models, but just do the feature extraction on a lot of CPUs at the same time.

Comment: I have performed some experiment (see my first post) and have come to the conclusion that the features extraction is, in fact, responsible. Though I can't verify that the memory bandwidth has been saturated, I think it's very likely.
Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.
I think there’s little that I can do if CountVectorizer is the problems. It seems that my best bet now is to do the parallel processing on different machines. :)

Comment: @PawinP Or do the vectorizing once, outside the parameter sweep.

Comment: I think that is not applicable in my case since my work also requires some hyper parameters optimization during the vectorization phase (especially the cut off threshold).

Comment: @PawinP With some work, such cutoffs might be replaced by a `feature_selection.varianceThreshold` estimator.